# .createreadstream value to string variable

Tags: node.js

How can I set a variable equal to the data that fs.createReadStream returns, so I can print out that variable and then I'll get the file contents.

```
var rs = fs.createReadStream('file.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'});
```

How can I get the returned data into a variable for later usage.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want all of the data at once in a variable, you should use `fs.readFile` instead.

```
fs.readFile('file.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'}, function(err, data){
    // Use the 'data' string here.
});
```

That said, depending on your use-case, it would be better to leave the data as a stream and process it in chunks as it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

I misinterpreted the question. Do it in this way

```
const file = await readFile('./logs.txt');
const text = file.toString();
```

You need async/await, or `file.readFileSync` instead. `createReadStream` is mostly used when you want to redirect the text stream to another.

If you need to collect the stream output to a string blob, I would do it this way.

```
function readFileString(stream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let result;
    stream.on("data", (d) => {
      result += d.toString();
    })
    stream.on("end", () => {
      resolve(result);
    })
    stream.on("error", () => {
      console.log('error')
      reject();
    })
  })
}
```

So you use it like `await readFileString(fs.createReadStream('./logs.txt'))`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -5):

This code will help:

```
var data = [];
var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');
CSV().from.stream(
                fs.createReadStream(file),
                {'escape': '\\'})
                .on('error', function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                })
                .on('record', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (row, index) {

                    data.push({
                        ESSID: row[0],
                        position: {
                            lat: row[4],
                            lng: row[5]
                        },
                        publicposition: {
                            lat: row[11],
                            lng: row[12]
                        },
                        publichost: row[13]
                    })

                }), function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                })
                .on('end', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (row, index) {
                   //do something with 'data'
                }))
```